# WPF Bind XSD Schema to TreeView

Tags: wpf, xsd, telerik, treeview, infragistics

The Table names of My DataSet will act as nodes of my tree view.
I want to bind XSD schema to the treeView the code I have tired is :
    System.IO.StreamReader xmlStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\code\depot\profile.xsd");
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(xmlStream);
            xmlStream.Close();
            return dataSet.Tables[0];
and 
    grid.ItemsSource = ViewModel.GetDataFromXML(); 
XAML

I can even use telerik/infragistics where ever it works.

Note: I would like to mention It is schema which will be shown in treeView and XSD doesnot contain any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 System.IO.StreamReader xmlStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\NORTHWNDDataSet.xsd");
 DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
 dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(xmlStream);
 xmlStream.Close();

 treeView.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables;
 reeView.DisplayMemberPath = "TableName";
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot!! I am able to show the Table Names as Node in Tree View. However it lost the Hierarchy Which was there in XSD and all tree nodes coming at the same level.     <a Name="a">
  <b Name="b">
     <x Name="x"/>
  </b>
  <c Name="c">
     <y Name="y"/>
  </c>
</a>         It is showing as 
 a
 b
 c
 x
 y  hope we are very close to the answer.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. DataSet has a Tables property which is a collection of tables and there is no tables hierarchy, hence they are displayed at 1 level.

Comment: yes, you are correct. in that case i will use the conventional way and not this shortcut ;)   :read the schema and created C# object and Bind it to tree view.